# C++ Array Arithmetic

Tags: c++, arrays, arithmetic-expressions

I am having trouble with a few lines of code in my C++ program. I am trying to take values from two arrays, preform some simple arithmetic and store the results in a third array. here is some of the code I have written. I checked to make sure that the first two arrays had values assigned. That's the only issue I could come up with because the third arrays elements are all still zero.

```
batAvg[i] = round((hits[i] / atBats[i]) * 1000);
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This question comes up a lot. Try `hits[i]*1000.0/atBats[i]`.

Comment: Sigh.  `(hits[i] * 1000 + 500) / atBats[i]`.  Adding 500 to do rounding, all as integers.

Comment: That definitely worked! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `batAvg` needs to be float or double. If it's an int, then the answer will be truncated to an integer (almost certainly 0) even if all the other values in the expression are floating point.

Comment: Oh, duh. I thought it was a floating point issue, but of course that's why the original code was multiplying by 1000. Sorry about that.